# Два и более UIScrollView в проекте

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Добавив первый View Controller и UIScrollView  в файл ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;

@end
```

И в файл ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize scroller;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 720)];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Все работает и отзывается!
При добавлении второго View Controller  пытаюсь привязать код *scroller к  UIScrollView, но во вкладке Referencing Outlets, scroller  не вижу там! Хотя для первого все было!

Прошу розьяснить правила установки для второго и если нужно 3го и тд окон.
Нужно чтобы каждое новое окно имело свой собственный скроллинг или идентичный.

[CCN.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r12m7kqtw54l41m/CCN.zip)

Спасибо!

Comment: Я правильно понял, что в Interface builder'е, в вашей Storyboard, ваш UIScrollView находится внутри вашего первого ViewController и вы пытаетесь привязать его к другим ViewController, внутри которых он... не находится?

Comment: Так уж повелось, что вопросы подобные вашему разруливаются гораздо быстрее и проще, если автор вопроса выкладывает в конце своего вопроса - ссылку на zip простейшего Xcode-проекта, демонстрирующего ситуацию, породившую вопрос. Сделайте это, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich

Спасибо за совет!

я прикрепил файл.

Comment: Лично я до сих пор не обновил Xcode до 5 версии, и поэтому, к сожалению, так и не смог открыть ваш файл. Попробую установить Xcode 5 завтра и разобраться в вашем проекте, если кто-нибудь (например, вы) не разберется в вашем вопросе раньше.

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря, я не увидел проблемы в вашем проекте - все готово к тому, чтобы добавлить скролл к соответствующему контроллеру. Поэтому в надежде, что я правильно понял постановку задачи, опишу шаги, которые вам нужно сделать:

В самом начале, при создании проекта, Apple сделала для вас дефолтный view controller в Storyboard и по умолчанию связала его с дефолтной парой файлов ViewController.h,m. И скорее всего, когда вы создавали свой первый скролл, вы начинали с того, что нажимали на "Scroll View" в вашем storyboard правой кнопкой мыши, нажимали на "New Referencing Outlet" и тянули линию к файлу ViewController.h, при отпускании вам всплывало окошко, где вы вводили имя `scroller` и у вас в заголовке ViewController.h появлялась строка вроде

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
```

Таким образом у вас оказывались связанными `Scroll View` в вашем Storyboard и ваш `scroller` в файле `ViewController`.

Теперь. Вы создаете новый (второй по счету) контроллер `View Controller` в вашей Storyboard. Вам теперь нужно сделать то же самое, что Apple сделала с первым `View Controller` за вас при авто-генерации проекта. Вам нужно создать новую пару файлов класса названием, например, AnotherViewController (этот класс также как и ViewController должен быть подклассом UIViewController), и связать эту новую пару с вашим новым View Controller из Storyboard: поищите в его вкладках поле `Custom class` и впишите в него  `AnotherViewController` - имя класса, который вы только что создали в файлах. То есть логика тут простая - создаете новый `View Controller` в Storyboard и сразу же создаете для него соответствующий подкласс UIViewController (это пара файлов - .h и .m), и связываете их вместе через поле `Custom class`.

После того, как ваш второй контроллер окажется связан с соответствующим классом AnotherViewController - вы берете его Scroll View, жмете на него правой кнопкой и тянете линию от New Referencing Outlet к открытому AnotherViewController.h файлу - и вам всплывет окошко при создании скролла точно также как это было с ViewController после авто-генерации проекта.

Comment: Ответ более чем развернутый!
Все новые View Controller теперь с UIScrollView *scroller 
Спасибо! 
)))